# Whats the best way to learn about VM implementation besides actually hacking code?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, vm-implementation

I'd like to learn more about VM implementation and optimization. Right now I'm contributing (in a small way) with JRuby and am also playing/writing with my own lisp-like language implementation that runs in a VM.

However I'd like to get more information on working with VM's and designing them. Is there a good resource for this type of information besides reading/working with existing code? I'm not opposed to do that, I just wondered if there were other sources I could be looking into.

Answer (score 5):

also check [The Implementation of Lua 5.0](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/doc/jucs05.pdf).  it's widely regarded as the fastest VM in its class and also one of the cleanest and smallest implementations.

Answer (score 5):

Read the work of Anton Ertl.  Also David Gregg.  Also you might want to read the [Smalltalk blue book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201113716) which has three chapters on the VM.  The [Smalltalk Green Book](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~ducasse/FreeBooks/BitsOfHistory/) is also interesting and is free online.

Less technical but still interesting, if you have access to the ACM Digital Library, is the grand-daddy of all portable VMs, [UCSD Pascal](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1500646).

Fninally, I second the recommendation of  [The Implementation of Lua 5.0](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/doc/jucs05.pdf).  This is superb work.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Level_Virtual_Machine) and [Parrot](http://www.parrot.org/).